# Building a Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to build a tree which holds integers and every element in the left subtree is <= node value.
This is the code that I have written so far but I don't know how to do the recursion inside. I would appreciate it if you could give me some guidance.

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Int Tree Tree
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord)

insert :: Int -> Tree -> Tree
insert x (Tree n i t1 t2) =
```

From what I understand is that I have to check each node of tree and see if there is an int to it and then recursively search the subtrees.
Please help

thanks

EDIT:

I managed to do something but it seems that the new nodes fail to be created or I am checking it wrong, this is the new code:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Int Tree Tree
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord)

insert :: Int -> Tree -> Tree
insert x Leaf = Node x Leaf Leaf
insert x (Node i t1 t2)  
              | x <= i    = insert x t1
              | otherwise = insert x t2
```

To check it I write:

```
let tree = insert 5 (insert 10 ( insert 11 ( insert 12 (insert 15 tree))))
```

But when I write in the ghci:

```
tree
```

I get:

```
Node 5 Leaf Leaf
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can check if there is a node where I am looking or not

Comment: I added an edit. please feel free to help me

Comment: did you mean `Leaf` instead of `tree` in the right hand side of `let tree = ...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are `insert`ing into a node, you are returning what would be `insert`ed into one side of the `Node`, not a new `Node` with the data `insert`ed into one side of it. Only at the `Leaf` level are you making a new node.

```
insert :: Int -> Tree -> Tree
insert x Leaf = Node x Leaf Leaf
insert x (Node i t1 t2)  
          | x <= i    = Node i (insert x t1)  t2
          | otherwise = Node i  t1           (insert x t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your recursive case for `Node` is that although you call `insert` to make a new sub tree on either the left or the right, you don't rebuild the parent tree afterwards, you just return the new sub tree.

For example the first case should be `Node i (insert x t1) t2`, and similarly for the second case.